# Compile file with vosk api with PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, vosk

I try to compile exe file from the python file with vosk library.
Compilation is ok.
Everytime when I try to run exe obtain this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Vega.py", line 10, in <module>
    from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer
  File "C:\Users\Alexandr\AppData\Local\Temp\embedded.zm51h3af.zip\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "vosk\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "vosk\__init__.py", line 12, in open_dll
  File "os.py", line 1111, in add_dll_directory
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The specified file cannot be found: 'C:\\Users\\Alexandr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI126762\\vosk'
[920] Failed to execute script Vega
```

What should I do?

Comment: It looks like your program has what `pyinstaller` calls a "hidden import". There is a very helpful section in the documentation called *When things go wrong*. I suggest you work through it. If you still have trouble you will need to edit your question to include your `.spec` file because that is where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

You need to create .spec file and write here something like that `datas=[('D:\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\vosk', './vosk')]`